# How to clear the effects of NSLayoutManager.drawGlyphsForGlyphRange(...)?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit, nslayoutmanager, nstextstorage

I have a `NSView` elements that are being reused primarily to draw different text as they scrolls within an `NSScrollView`. I am using the trio of `NSTextStorage, NSLayoutManager and NSTextContainer` to display the text and the following is the  call made to draw the text within the drawRect method:

```
layoutManager.drawGlyphsForGlyphRange(glyphRange, atPoint: NSMakePoint(0, 0))
```

What I am seeing is that on successive calls to `drawRect` it overlays the new text to be drawn on top of the old text effectively creating a big mess/pile of text visually.

What is the best way of clearing the text drawn on the last call to drawRect, specifically with scrolling performance in mind:

A) Calling `NSRectFill` in `drawRect` prior to drawing the text - this effectively paints over the previous text and is pretty simple. It just seems wasteful to keep painting the same background over-and-over on every scroll.

B) Look into `NSView.prepareForReuse()` - this approach would seem better suited to a scenario where you want to "wipe" the whole content of the existing object to reuse and start from a different state. In my scenario, it is just the previous text written from `NSLayoutManager` that I want to get rid of.

C) Some other approach?